# Increment Row Number on Range Time in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working on SQL Lite query that needs to return a column 'purchase_id' **based on a range of time and a user**. I have two columns: *user_name* and *purchase_date*. If another purchase(s) is made by the same user within the **10 minutes** following the first puchase(s), we assign the same id to the other purchase(s). Otherwise, we assigned a new puchase_id. Example.

This would be the input:

```
User     | Purchase_Date         
---------------------------------
John     | '2019-07-01 12:31:10' 
John     | '2019-07-01 12:35:10' 
John     | '2019-07-01 17:53:35' 
Paul     | '2019-07-01 07:31:30'        
Paul     | '2019-07-02 19:33:35'
Paul     | '2019-07-02 19:33:45'
Paul     | '2019-07-02 19:35:07'
Paul     | '2019-07-03 14:11:30'       
Paul     | '2019-07-03 14:15:25'
Paul     | '2019-07-06 22:33:35'
```

And this would be the output

```
User     | Purchase_Date         | purchase_id
----------------------------------------------
John     | '2019-07-01 12:31:10' | 1
John     | '2019-07-01 12:35:10' | 1
John     | '2019-07-01 17:53:35' | 2
Paul     | '2019-07-01 07:31:30' | 1           
Paul     | '2019-07-02 19:33:35' | 2
Paul     | '2019-07-02 19:33:45' | 2
Paul     | '2019-07-02 19:35:07' | 2
Paul     | '2019-07-03 14:11:30' | 3           
Paul     | '2019-07-03 14:15:25' | 3
Paul     | '2019-07-06 22:33:35' | 4
```

I suppose there are different ways to perform it. I think one solution would be to use DENSE_RANK() OVER and some partition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server or SQLite? Which RDBMS are you *really* using? Only tag 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Look at the previous time to see where a new "session" begins.  Then a cumulative sum of the "news" is what you want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_pd >= datetime(purchase_date, '-10 minutes') then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by user order by purchase_date) as purchase_id
from (select t.*, 
             lag(purchase_date) over (partition by user order by purchase_date) as prev_pd
      from t
       ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using row_number()

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by user order by strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H', Purchase_Date)) as rn
from tablename
```